# Get Employees with invoices at 2 or more markets within any week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that looks at 1 years worth of invoices and determines how many employees have invoices at 2 or more stores that are in the same market and within any given week.  Edit: Essentially, I need to find employees that are working at two stores at the same time within the same week.

I'm getting close but can't quite get the query to work.  I've tried joining the invoice table to itself with a date condition where left side is between right side + a week. It's not quite doing what I want.

In the example code only the first two employees have an invoice in multiple markets within a week period.

EDIT: I realized the below examples work if the week is based on calendar.  I need it to be a rolling 7 days window that's not based on calendar.  So invoice date + 7 days, which is why I was attempting to do the self join.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/17f19/1)

Example Code:

```
DROP TABLE [tmp].[store]
CREATE TABLE [tmp].[store](
            [storepk] int NOT null IDENTITY(1,1), 
            [storename] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            [storemarket] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            [store_id] int null         
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


DROP TABLE [tmp].[storeinvoices]
CREATE TABLE [tmp].[storeinvoices](
            [invoicepk] int NOT null IDENTITY(1,1), 
            [storeemployee_id] int null, 
            [store_id] int null, 
            [invoicedate] datetime null
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DROP TABLE [tmp].[storeemployee]
CREATE TABLE [tmp].[storeemployee](
            [storeemployeepk] int NOT null IDENTITY(1,1), 
            [storeemployee_id] int null, 
            [store_id] int null, 
            [fname] VARCHAR(20) null,
            [lname] VARCHAR(20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

DROP TABLE [tmp].[storeemployeeglobal]
CREATE TABLE [tmp].[storeemployeeglobal](
            [storeemployeeglobalpk] int NOT null IDENTITY(1,1), 
            [masterstoreemployee_id] int not null,
            [storeemployee_id] int null, 
            [store_id] int null
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [tmp].[storeemployee]
SELECT 1,1,'steve','johnson' UNION
SELECT 2,2,'steve','johnson' UNION
SELECT 3,3,'steve','johnson' UNION
SELECT 4,1,'adam','thomas' UNION
SELECT 5,2,'adam','thomas' UNION
SELECT 6,1,'susan','smith' UNION
SELECT 7,3,'susan','smith'

INSERT INTO [tmp].[storeemployeeglobal]
SELECT 1,1,1 UNION
SELECT 1,2,2 UNION
SELECT 1,3,3 UNION
SELECT 2,4,1 UNION
SELECT 2,5,2 UNION
SELECT 3,6,1 UNION
SELECT 3,7,3


INSERT INTO [tmp].[store]
SELECT 'Down Town Store', 'South', 1 UNION
SELECT 'East Side Store','East', 2 UNION
SELECT 'South City Store','South', 3

INSERT INTO [tmp].[storeinvoices]
SELECT 1,1,'2018/1/1' UNION
SELECT 1,1,'2018/1/5' UNION
SELECT 1,1,'2018/2/1' UNION
SELECT 1,1,'2018/2/12' UNION
SELECT 1,1,'2018/3/15' UNION
SELECT 2,2,'2018/2/15' UNION
SELECT 3,3,'2018/3/25' UNION
SELECT 4,1,'2018/1/5' UNION
SELECT 4,1,'2018/1/25' UNION
SELECT 4,1,'2018/2/1' UNION
SELECT 4,1,'2018/2/15' UNION
SELECT 5,2,'2018/1/27' UNION
SELECT 6,1,'2018/1/11' UNION
SELECT 6,1,'2018/3/15' UNION
SELECT 7,3,'2018/5/15'

SELECT * 
FROM [tmp].[storeinvoices] AS i
INNER JOIN [tmp].[storeemployeeglobal] AS eg
    ON i.[storeemployee_id] = eg.[storeemployee_id]
    AND i.[store_id] = eg.[store_id]
INNER JOIN [tmp].[store] AS s
    ON i.[store_id] = s.[store_id]
ORDER BY eg.[masterstoreemployee_id], i.[invoicedate]
```

Comment: doesn't only storeemplyee_id 1 fit this explanation?

Comment: No, each employee has an employee_id at each store.  So I need to join to the storeemployeeglobal table to get their masterstoreemployee_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT i.storeemployee_id, DATEPART(week, invoicedate)
FROM [storeinvoices] AS i
INNER JOIN [storeemployeeglobal] AS eg
    ON i.[storeemployee_id] = eg.[storeemployee_id]
    AND i.[store_id] = eg.[store_id]
INNER JOIN [store] AS s
    ON i.[store_id] = s.[store_id]
GROUP BY i.storeemployee_id,DATEPART(week, invoicedate)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column_that_indicate_market)>=2
```

Comment: The trick is it needs to be two invoices that aren't at the same market.  Essentially, I need to find employees that are working at two stores at the same time within the same week.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Then use COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the SQL fiddle to show my changes to your code to better reflect my needs (using master employee ID and store market).  I think your code is working.  You are grouping by the assigned week value (from datediff) and I never would have thought to do that.  This makes sense to do now that I see it.  Thank you, after validating some more if everything is working I'll mark as answered!

Comment: If I wanted to change it to be for a 2 week or 3 week window what's the best way to approach?

Comment: @CodeMonkey If all your values are from one year then simple integer division`DATEPART(week, invoicedate)/2` should handle the case. For instance 14/2 = 7 and 15/2 = 7

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I did realize that I need to do this all based on a rolling 7 day week and not just on calendar week.  I think I've created a solution in my sqlfiddle solution.  If you have a second please check if it looks like it makes sense (it's the bottom query).  I'm still marking you as the answer since I was not clear in my original question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any data that meets your requirement in the SQL Fiddle.  Also, you are vague on what "week" means.  This should give you an idea on what to do:

```
SELECT i.storeemployee_id, datepart(iso_week, i.invoicedate) as week, count(*)
FROM storeinvoices i INNER JOIN
     store  s
     ON i.store_id = s.store_id
GROUP BY i.storeemployee_id, datepart(iso_week, i.invoicedate)
HAVING MIN(s.storemarket) <> MAX(s.storemarket);
```

This uses `iso_week`, so the definition of week is not affected by partial weeks at the end/beginning of each year.

Comment: The data meets the requirement when the invoice table is joined to the masteremployee table.  Each employee has a unique ID at each store, so it must be joined to get the master ID.  Thanks for the response I'm looking at the code now but I believe there's a working answer above in addition to this one.

Comment: I checked your code and updated the SQL Fiddle.  Your code works, thanks!